# How to fix event listener issues of react js from mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, solidity

I have a react js app.
And it has one solidity event listener
Listener works fine the first time I use the app

But when I press home button or go to another app from the browser and reopen the browser after sometimes(1/2 minutes), the listener stops listening and it only starts listening again after refreshing the app.

So is there any solution with that I can handle it?

My code

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    
    if (isMounted && props.blockchain.smartContract != null && props.blockchain.smartContract != undefined && props.users.length != 0) {

      props.blockchain.smartContract.events.Transfer({}).on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
        console.log(subscriptionId);
        console.log("Subscription ID")
    }).on('data', event => {

          
          let item = { key:event.transactionHash,sender: event.returnValues.from, recipient: event.returnValues.to, value: event.returnValues.value / (10 ** 18), type_id: '1', interval: '1s' }
          
          setFeed(item,event)
          
          console.log(event.transactionHash)
         


        })
        .on('changed', function(event){
            // remove event from local database
            
            
        })
        .on('error', function(error, receipt) { // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
            console.log(error)
            setCointEvent(Math.random() * 100)
        });
    }
    return (()=>{
      isMounted = false
      
    })
  }, [props.blockchain.smartContract, props.users,coinEvent]);
```

Does react js hooks understand if user closes the browser?

Answer (score 0):

window.onload = function (){
//your function here // maybe it works. It works in everys JS file perfectly.

//It will allow your functions to happen from page loads.

//you can add listener here it will listen.
}

Comment: Sorry but maybe I couldn't properly explain the problem. The browser is not closed. Let's say you are a user and you come to my app, listeners are working fine, then you press home button or maybe you move to another app from the browser directly and when you come back, the listeners stop working.